# Hibernate query on string list in entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider an entity

```
@Entity
class Book{
  ...
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
  ...
}
```

What should be the hibernate query so one can get all the books containing any multiple tag "hobbit,sherlock,fiction"(OR operation splitted by comma).Any query(HQL,Criteria or raw SQL) will work,though Criteria is prefered.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by myself but not using  pure criteria

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("BOOK_ID IN " +
            "(SELECT BOOK_ID FROM Book_tags " + 
            "WHERE tags ='" + tag + "')"));
```

Please note the single quote surrounding the query parameter 'tag' .Pure criteria query is always welcomed.